# Pickers are overlapping in ios 15 preventing some of them to be scrolled

Tags: swift, swiftui

I Created a custom time picker in Swiftui to enter a desired time, the picker works by having multiple picker next to each other, to select time values, ie there is a picker for hours, minutes, seconds and miliseconds. With iOS 14 this worked perfectly but since updating to iOS 15 only one picker works at a time. This seems to be because the pickers are now overlapping. To me it seems that setting the frame is not working properly, but I am unsure how to fix this issue.

The code consists of a TimePickerClass which stores the values of the time pickers:

```
class TimePickerClass: ObservableObject {
    @Published var hoursTime = 0
    @Published var secondsTime = 0
    @Published var milisecondsTime = 0
    @Published var minutesTime : Int  = 0
    
    func GetTime() -> Double {
        return Double(hoursTime) * 3600.0 + Double(minutesTime) * 60.0 + Double(secondsTime) + Double(milisecondsTime)/100
    }
    
    func GetTimeString() -> String {
        return TimeFormatted(timeInSeconds: GetTime())
    }
    
    func Reset(){
        hoursTime = 0
        secondsTime = 0
        milisecondsTime = 0
        minutesTime = 0
    }
}
```

And this is the TimePicker view

```
struct TimePicker: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel : TimePickerClass
    
    let pickerColor : Color = AppColor.PickerColors.backgroundColor
    let textColor : Color = AppColor.PickerColors.textColor
    let width :CGFloat = 30
    var body: some View {
        HStack
        {
            
            HStack(alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, spacing: 0){
                Spacer()
                Picker("", selection: $viewModel.hoursTime) {
                    ForEach(0..<24){ hours in
                        if(hours < 10){
                            Text("  \(hours)").foregroundColor(textColor)
                        }
                        else{
                            Text("\(hours)").foregroundColor(textColor)
                        }
                    }
                }.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle()).frame(width: width, height: 40).clipped().labelsHidden().clipShape(Rectangle())
                
                Text(":").foregroundColor(textColor)
                
                Picker("", selection: $viewModel.minutesTime) {
                    ForEach(0..<60){ minutes in
                        if(minutes < 10){
                            Text("0\(minutes)").foregroundColor(textColor)
                        }
                        else{
                            Text("\(minutes)").foregroundColor(textColor)
                        }
                    }
                }.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle()).frame(width: width, height: 40).clipped().labelsHidden().clipShape(Rectangle())
                
                Text(":").foregroundColor(textColor)
                
                Picker("", selection: $viewModel.secondsTime) {
                    ForEach(0..<60){ seconds in
                        if(seconds < 10){
                            Text("0\(seconds)").foregroundColor(textColor)
                        }
                        else{
                            Text("\(seconds)").foregroundColor(textColor)
                        }
                    }
                }.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle()).frame(width: width, height: 40).clipped().labelsHidden().clipShape(Rectangle())
                
                Text(".").foregroundColor(textColor)
                
                Picker("", selection: $viewModel.milisecondsTime) {
                    ForEach(0..<100){ miliSeconds in
                        if(miliSeconds < 10){
                            Text("0\(miliSeconds)").foregroundColor(textColor)
                        }
                        else{
                            Text("\(miliSeconds)").foregroundColor(textColor)
                        }
                    }
                }.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .frame(width: width, height: 40)
                    .clipped()
                    .clipShape(Rectangle())
                Spacer()
            }.padding(.leading).padding(.trailing).overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(pickerColor, lineWidth: 2))
        }.background(pickerColor.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))).overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1))
    }
}
```

To test it use:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var testTimePicker = TimePickerClass()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            TimePicker(viewModel: testTimePicker)
            Text("\(String(testTimePicker.GetTime()))")
            Text(testTimePicker.GetTimeString())
            
        }
}
```

iOS 14

[image: Screen recording ios 15]

iOS 15

[image: Screen recording ios 15]

Comment: You mean the customized time picker not custom time picker, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try adding

```
.compositingGroup()
.clipped()
```

to your Pickers.