# SwiftUI - Pickers overlapping

Tags: swiftui, picker

I'm trying to create a component that's basically two SwiftUI pickers right next to eachother, like this: [image]

Right now its just a super simple implementation:

```
@State var hourSelection = 0
@State var daySelection = 0

var days = [Int](0 ..< 30)
var hours = [Int](0 ..< 30)
```

...

```
GeometryReader { proxy in
  HStack(spacing: 0) {
    Picker(selection: self.$daySelection, label: Text("")) {
      ForEach(0 ..< self.days.count) { index in
        Text("\(self.days[index]) d").tag(index)
      }
    }
    .pickerStyle(.wheel)
    .frame(width: proxy.size.width / 2, height: proxy.size.height, alignment: .leading)

    Picker(selection: self.$hourSelection, label: Text("")) {
      ForEach(0 ..< self.hours.count) { index in
        Text("\(self.hours[index]) h").tag(index)
      }
    }
    .pickerStyle(.wheel)
    .frame(width: proxy.size.width / 2, height: proxy.size.height, alignment: .trailing)
  }
}
```

**Trying to use the picker on the left simple uses the picker on the right.** In other words, they overlap. How can I fix this using SwiftUI? No other solutions on Stack Overflow have worked for me.

I have looked at [Pickers are overlapping in ios 15 preventing some of them to be scrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69365738/pickers-are-overlapping-in-ios-15-preventing-some-of-them-to-be-scrolled) but the accepted solution does not work for me.

I tried using `.compositingGroup()` followed by `.clipped()` after the .frame(), but this has not worked, nor has applying `.mask(Rectangle())` to the parent container.

Update: Even with the iOS 16 update and new XCode Beta, the problem remains the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pickers are overlapping in ios 15 preventing some of them to be scrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69365738/pickers-are-overlapping-in-ios-15-preventing-some-of-them-to-be-scrolled)

Comment: No, unfortunately I do not believe that solution still works.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible variant - just to make underlying `UIPickerView` (because it is it responsible for the issue) to be compressible:

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

```
extension UIPickerView {
    override open func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()
        self.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
    }
}
```

[Test module on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestMultiPickersInRow.swift)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm looking for something with the aesthetic of the picture in the question, where the gray highlight goes across the different wheels.

Comment: Then you need this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/63970044/12299030.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try later today.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
extension UIPickerView {
    open override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: super.intrinsicContentSize.height)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try adding `.clipped()`, **after** each `.frame(width: proxy...)`. Works for me on macos 12.5, using Xcode 13.3, targets ios-15 macCatalyst 12.3, tested on real devices only.